# Cast NSManagedObject to subclassed object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is there a way to cast an NSManagedObject to a sub-classed object?

I have `@interface Contact :  NSManagedObject` and in a generic part of my code I have an `NSManagedObject`, I would like to cast it to `Contact` to be able to access properties directly using `contact.firstName` etc...

I am using `Contact *contact = myManagedObject;` which works at run time but I am getting the compiler warning `warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSManagedObject *', expected 'struct Contact *'` that I would like to suppress.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a C cast:

```
Contact *contact = (Contact *) myManagedObject;
```

Be aware that this is quite a bit of rope.  Sometimes necessary rope, certainly.

Comment: this isn't working for me: Contact *contact = (Contact*)object;
        DLog(@"The <explative> class of contact is: %@", [contact class]); //prints NSManagedObject
        contact.Address = addressObject;

Comment: If you don't have the model set to create instances of your subclass, you'll get NSManagedObject instances.  Casting can never change the class of an object.